# Kubernetes: security context and IPC_LOCK capability

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm trying to install a helm package that needs `IPC_LOCK` capability. So, I'm getting this message:

> Error creating: pods "pod..." is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context constraint: [capabilities.add: Invalid value: "IPC_LOCK": capability may not be added capabilities.add: Invalid value: "IPC_LOCK": capability may not be added]

You can see the `DeploymentConfig` [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/incubator/vault/templates/deployment.yaml#L61).

I'm installing Vault using a Helm chart, so I'm not able to change `DeploymentConfig`.

I guess the only way to get it would be using a service account with an `scc` associated allowing it to perform the container.

How could I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on vault yet, so my answers might not be accurate.

But I think you can remove that capability and disable m_lock in vault config. 
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/index.html#disable_mlock

Having said that, I don't think kubernetes supports memory swapping anyway (someone needs to verify this) therefore a syscall to mlock might not be needed.

Comment: My question was heading up to how to create an user or service account is able to run this container. Since it's a helm chart, I'm not able to change `DeployConfig`

Comment: I see. Yeah the way to go with openshift is by serviceaccount and scc privileged pod.  Not too familiar with openshift though. . Ijust came across this github issue in vault.  https://github.com/coreos/vault-operator/issues/311. At any rate, you can always do a helm fetch to get the charts and update the chart yourself.